# 'str' object is not callable Hangman command Discord

Tags: python, discord

so i was making a hangman command but it just says `'str' object is not callable`
that error message popped up when i was polishing the command please tell me how to fix it

heres my hangman code

```
gameStart = False
words = ["words i put"]

pickedword = "No picked words currently!"


def word_selected_dashed():
  if pickedword == "No picked words currently!":
    return
  else:
    global selectedword
    selectedword = []
    for i in range(len(pickedword)):
      selectedword.append('?')
  return ''.join(selectedword)

@client.command()
async def hangman(ctx):
  global gameStart
  global pickedword
  global trials
  
  pickedword = random.choice(words)
  if gameStart == True:
    await ctx.send("There is a game ongoing please use `sus hangmanstop` to stop")
  else: 
    gameStart = True
    await ctx.send("Game Started")
    lettercount = 0
    for letters in pickedword:
      lettercount += 1  
  await ctx.send(f"This word has {lettercount} letters!")
  word_selected_dashed()

@client.command()
async def guess(ctx, letterput : str):
  getattr(str, 'lower')
  letter = letterput.lower()
  if pickedword == "No picked words currently!":
    await ctx.send("No game found! Please use `sus hangman` to start a game!")
    return False
  if letter in alphabet and gameStart == True:
    print(letter)
  elif letter == pickedword:
    await ctx.send("You guess the word!")
    await hangmanstop(ctx)
    return
  elif gameStart == False:
    await ctx.send("You havent started a game!")
    return False
  global guessed_word
  global word_selected_dashed
  global trials
  trials = 7
  word_selected_dashed = word_selected_dashed()
  gussed_word = list(word_selected_dashed)

  if letter in pickedword:
    for i in range(len(pickedword)):
      
      if list(pickedword)[i] == letter:
        gussed_word[i] = letter
        await ctx.send(''.join(gussed_word))
  elif letter not in pickedword:
    await ctx.send('wrong!')
    trials -= 1
    await ctx.send(f"You only have {trials} guesses left!")
  if trials == 0:
    await ctx.send("You lost!")
    await hangmanstop(ctx)
    return

@client.command()
async def hangmanstop(ctx):
  global gameStart
  if gameStart == True:
    gameStart = False
    await ctx.send("Current game stopped!")
  else:
    await ctx.send("No game found | Please use `sus hangman` to start a game!")
```

idk what is making the problem
i looked at the terminal very closely but i cant find the code making it error
i know its a str error but everytime i try to fix it same error please help me

Comment: `word_selected_dashed = word_selected_dashed()` will surely give you headaches next time you use the `word_selected_dashed` function!

Comment: yeah it actually did

Comment: I think that is the cause of your error… thinking about it… the first time it runs fine, the second time the output of the function the first time (a string object) is not callable and you’re calling it with `word_selected_dashed = word_selected_dashed()` the parentheses are what calls that callable, but after the first time it is turned into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `“lower”` attribute of a `str` callable on the first line of your `guess` method as highlighted below.

```
async def guess(ctx, letterput : str):
  getattr(str, 'lower')
```

Remove the `getattr()` call altogether.

Comment: It's useless but it's not the cause of an error.

Comment: i just figured it out that i just need to make the pickedword a function thanks for your help though!